# chromium cannot load nss libraries?

Tags: opensuse, chrome

I'm using openSUSE 12.2 64-bit with a special kernel but with chromium it gives me

```
[0220/130849:ERROR:nss_util.cc(724)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
[1:1:0220/130850:ERROR:nss_util.cc(724)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
[0220/130850:ERROR:nss_util.cc(724)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
[1:1:0220/130850:ERROR:nss_util.cc(724)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
```

I have a symlink of nss folder in `/usr/lib/nss` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nss`.  When I start strace chromium it doesn't give me the path to the nss librariers. The strange thing is chromium is stopped working after an update?  Maybe this is cross repo error between beta (factory) and default repo librariers? Do I really need to fix it myself?

Update: I was wrong and I don't have any factory repo enabled:

```
1 | openSUSE-12.2-12.2-1.14 | openSUSE-12.2-12.2-1.14      | Nein      | Nein         
2 | repo-debug              | openSUSE-12.2-Debug          | Nein      | Ja           
3 | repo-debug-update       | openSUSE-12.2-Update-Debug   | Nein      | Ja           
4 | repo-non-oss            | openSUSE-12.2-Non-Oss        | Ja        | Ja           
5 | repo-oss                | openSUSE-12.2-Oss            | Ja        | Ja           
6 | repo-source             | openSUSE-12.2-Source         | Nein      | Ja           
7 | repo-update             | openSUSE-12.2-Update         | Ja        | Ja           
8 | repo-update-non-oss     | openSUSE-12.2-Update-Non-Oss | Ja        | Ja
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works! Some libraries were missing and wrong version. Especially in usr/lib64/ these files:

- libmozsqlite3.so
- libsoftokn3.so
- libnssutil3.so
- libnss3.so

But I have deinstalled chromium and installed google-chrome. However I didn't tried it with Chromium.